# Expansion of time-ordered products of spinor 4-point correlation function

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I was reading Schwartz's QFT and in section 13.1.1, he raised the definition

$G_4(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\langle\Omega|\mathscr{T}\{\psi(x_1)\bar\psi(x_3)\psi(x_2)\bar\psi(x_4)\}|\Omega\rangle$

and claimed that the first nonzero perturbation contribution gives

$G_4=(-\mathrm{i}e)^2\int\mathrm{d}^4x\int\mathrm{d}^4y\langle0|\mathscr{T}\{\psi(x_1)\bar\psi(x_3)\psi(x_2)\bar\psi(x_4)\Big(\bar\psi(x)A\!\!\!/(x)\psi(x)\Big)\Big(\bar\psi(y)A\!\!\!/(y)\psi(y)\Big)\}|0\rangle$

and I'm confused with this formula. Where did the $\bar\psi A\!\!\!/\psi$ term come from? Does it come from something like $|\Omega\rangle\sim \bar\psi A\!\!\!/\psi|0\rangle$?

Comment: Could you please provide further details? The questions are meant to be self-contained

Comment: I don't have the book, but I'm guessing that you're in the chapter about QED. These terms come from the interaction terms of the Lagrangian, and he's performing a perturbative expansion in the charge $e$. You can interpret this as a Feynman digram with the fermions exchanging only one photon